# How can I check if ncurses is installed?

Tags: linux, redhat

How can I check if ncurses is installed in a Red-Hat Linux OS? One solution is to use

```
dpkg -l '*ncurses*' | grep '^ii'
```

But I don't even have the dpkg package in my system, and since I don't have the administrative rights, I can't install it.

Answer (score 9):

On RedHat based systems there is (mostly) no `dpkg` but you can use `rpm -qa | grep ncurse`

Answer (score 1):

on mac:

```
prompt> ls -la /usr/include/ncurses.h
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  8 11 jul 14:24 /usr/include/ncurses.h -> curses.h
```

The second line being not empty, this means ncurses is installed.